# NullReferenceException while parsing XML File

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, nullreferenceexception

**My Goal:** I want to parse a XML file for Catalog Number **987654** and display it in a textbox. My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This file was generated by the installer. -->
<ModificationMap>
     <replace>
     <replace>
     <replace>
          <!-- Changed Serial Number and Product ID -->
          <text symbol="__EXAMPLE_SERIALNUMBER__">123456789</text>
          <text symbol="__EXAMPLE_CATALOGNUMBER__">987654</text>
          <text symbol="__MY_XMLPROGRAM__">300</text>
          <text symbol="__REGISTRATION_EXAMPLE__">20</text>
          <text symbol="__REGISTRATION_EXAMPLEVERSION__">20</text>
               <!-- Asset Profile -->
          <text symbol="__ASSET_MEMBERNAME__">MY_PROGRAM</text>
          <text symbol="__ASSET_FRIENDLYNAME__">XMLFile</text>
          <text symbol="__ASSET_DESCRIPTION__">XMLFile</text>
     </replace>
     <replace>
     <delete>
     <replace>
     <replace>
</ModificationMap>
```

Code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dict = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Smith\Desktop\example.xml")
        .Descendants("text")
        .ToDictionary(f => f.Attribute("__EXAMPLE_CATALOGNUMBER__").Value,
                      f => f.Attribute("symbol").Value);
        textBox1.Text = dict["__EXAMPLE_CATALOGNUMBER__"];
    }
```

I am getting an error telling me:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled.

I think this approach to my goal is wrong. I am new to C# coding.

Comment: can you post the XML as Code not as image?

Comment: Are you trying to search for the `<text>` element that has a `symbol` attribute with value `__REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER__`?

Comment: do you mean to search for __EXAMPLE_CATALOGNUMBER__ ?

Comment: @appcoder: Yes, EXAMPLE_CATALOGNUMBER. I want that 987654 to be displayed in the textbox.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks. I will read it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this code:

```
f.Attribute("__REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER__").Value
```

there is not attribute named `__REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER__`. Now, you might want to do something more along these lines:

```
f.Attributes().Where(a => a.Value == "__REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER__")
    .First().Value;
```

but even at that, I'm not sure what that would accomplish.

At any rate, `f.Attribute("__REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER__").Value` is going to throw a `NullReferenceException` because `Attribute(...)` is going to return `null`.

***It's quite likely what you're really looking for is this:***

```
.ToDictionary(f => f.Attribute("symbol").Value,
              f => f.Value);
```

that would give you the symbol -> element value KVP.

Comment: @Smith, but it's likely that some of the other `symbol` values repeat. Either narrow down the search by adding a `Where` before the `ToDictionary`, or concatenate two values (you'll have to figure out which ones) to create a unique key.